# Swift: How do I add data to a variable of an object in a list of objects

Tags: swift, list, class, object

I have 3 layers of data I'm getting from an xml that I need to store

1: Start time and end time

2: IP and mac address of a host

3: Port number and service of each host IP

The approach I used to solve this was to create 3 classes and let each have variables for the data like so:

```
class Ports {
var scanPortNumber: [String] = [""]
var scanProtocol: [String] = [""]
}

class Hosts {
    var hostPorts = [Ports]()
    var scanHostIP: [String] = [""]
    var scanHostMacAddr: [String] = [""]
}

class Scan {
    var scanHosts = [Hosts]()
    var scanStartTime: [String] = [""]
    var scanEndTime: [String] = [""]
}
```

then I declared a global object where i'm parsing the xml like this:

```
var scanDetails = Scan()
```

so I could store the IP's I get from the xml like this:

```
scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostIP[i] = "the IP I get from parsing the xml"
```

here is how I'm trying to store the data:

```
var scanDetails = Scan()

class XMLRead: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    var hostIP = ""
    var hostMacAddr = ""
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        
        var i = 0
        
        if !elementName.isEmpty {
            
            switch elementName {
                
                case "address":
                    print("i in address = \(i)")
                    let addrType = attributeDict["addrtype"]
                    if addrType == "ipv4" {
                        let hostIPtmp = attributeDict["addr"]
                        if hostIPtmp != hostIP || hostIP == "" {
                            hostIP = hostIPtmp!
                            scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostIP[i] = hostIP
                        }
                    }
                    else if addrType == "mac" {
                        let hostMacAddrtmp = attributeDict["addr"]
                        if hostMacAddrtmp != hostMacAddr || hostMacAddr == "" {
                            hostMacAddr = hostMacAddrtmp!
                            scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostMacAddr[i] = hostMacAddr
                        }
                    }
                    print("hostIP = \(scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostIP[i])")
                    print("hostMacAddr = \(scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostMacAddr[i])")
                
                default:    break
            }
            
            i += 1
            print("i = \(i)")
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
        print("failure error: \(parseError)")
    }
}
```

but this method doesn't seem to be working since it gives me the `**Index out of range error**` when I do this. So i tried using the `append()` method but it said I had to append a `Hosts` type and didn't allow me to append the value I get from the xml since it was a string.

I'm pretty new to swift so if someone can please tell me what am I doing wrong and how do I can fix it i'd be grateful.

Comment: You should use `append()` when adding elements to an array. You can read about arrays in swift [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107). A note on your design, you have made everything into arrays but is that really necessary, for instance shouldn’t scanStartTime be a String instead of an array?.

Comment: Yes the array for the scanStartTime was a mistake on my part sorry, but like i said ```So i tried using the append() method but it said I had to append a Hosts type and didn't allow me to append the value I get from the xml since it was a string```

Comment: Consider that `var scanHostIP: [String] = [""]` creates an array with one entry, an empty string. This might be not indended. And as already mentioned by others you cannot assign elements with index subscription if there is no item at the given index.

Comment: You need to so this step by step, you get a string from the xml then you create an object from the string and add the object to an array of some other object

Comment: Your code will look a lot cleaner if you had chosen a struct instead of a class.

Comment: @vadian like i said i used append but that said i needed to pass a variable of the same type as the class to it so how would i do that? Joakim Danielson said i would need to do it step by step but i'm not sure how to add an object to the array like he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply run the code that you have provided:
I would make these following changes:

```
.
.
var i = 0
var host: Hosts?
.
.
if hostIPtmp != hostIP || hostIP == "" {

   hostIP = hostIPtmp!
   host = Hosts()
   host!.scanHostIP.append(hostIP)
                        
   scanDetails.scanHosts.append(host!)
}
.
.
.
if hostMacAddrtmp != hostMacAddr || hostMacAddr == "" {
   hostMacAddr = hostMacAddrtmp!

   if host == nil {
      host = Hosts()
   }
   host!.scanHostMacAddr.append(hostMacAddr)
   scanDetails.scanHosts.append(host!)
}
.
.
```

But i don't understand, why you are using 'i' and variables of the classes as Arrays, if you are only going to put one value inside each of them.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this. This is just an example there are more values that's why i'm using the "i".

Comment: So basically there is going to be an iteration after all.
Well Just try to understand how i am initiating custom types and passing it on, you will get the idea how it works and then apply it to the iteration logic.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :P

Answer (score 1):

Lets focus on your `scanDetails.scanHosts[i]` first:

- Lets assume array 'scanHosts' has only 2 elements, so how many indexes does it have at this point? Answer: '0' and '1'
- Meaning `scanDetails.scanHosts[0] = "Blah blah blah"` will work
- Also meaning `scanDetails.scanHosts[1] = "Blah blah blah"` will also work
- But if the value of 'i' is '2', meaning `scanDetails.scanHosts[2] = "Blah blah blah"`, it will give you an exception. Because index '2' does not exist.

Same goes for the next part of your statement `.scanHostIP[i]` which is after `scanDetails.scanHosts[i]`

I recommend you share your for loop code here so we can help more regarding this issue of yours

Comment: I'm not using a for loop per say i just keep a variable ```i``` and after the parser goes through all cases in the switch block once I increment ```i```. So it starts from 0 and then increments but here's the thing how I can access the variable if it isn't initialize since  ```scanHosts``` is an instance of the class ```Hosts``` it act's like a custom type now my problem is how do I initialize a custom type?

Comment: I highly recommend you share your piece of code here, specially the part where you are filling up the array.

Answer (score 0):

When You create an object like as..
var scanDetails = Scan().
The atributes of scanDetails that means
scanHosts, scanStartTime, scanEndTime arrays are empty. When allocate memory  or insert value in array then You access those index of array

You can create an array with initialized.like as..
var myDoubles = [Double](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0.0)
This would create an array of 10 doubles, all initialized with the value of 0.0. Now you access the index 0 to 9.

Comment: ok but how would I initialize something like ```var scanHosts = [Hosts]()```? because that is the problem here. I want to access ```scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostIP[i]``` so I can store the IP values there.

Comment: You can set initializer in each class and those initializer initialize the array by some default array type value

Comment: How do i do that in this case since it's a class which acts as a custom type?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Ports {
    var scanPortNumber: [String]
    var scanProtocol: [String]
}

struct Hosts {
    var hostPorts : [Ports]
    var scanHostIP: [String]
    var scanHostMacAddr: [String]
}

struct Scan {
    var scanHosts : [Hosts]
    var scanStartTime: [String]
    var scanEndTime: [String]
}
```

Try using a `struct` instead of a `class`, it will make your code a lot cleaner.

Comment: The reason you got the "Index Out Of Range ", is probably because one of your arrays's size was smaller than the count variable.

Comment: Can I access ```scanHostIP``` the same way I do with the class ie. ```Scan.scanHosts[i].scanHostIP[i]``` ?

Comment: Yeah, you can, as long as 'i' is not greater than the current size of the scanHostIP array. The problem with your code is that you are trying to access an index 'scanDetails.scanHosts[i].scanHostIP[i] = hostIP' that is not yet initialized.